# Sorting algorithm for list of integers

Tags: sorting

I have a list of about 200 integers whose values are between 1 and 5.

I want to get into learning about sorting algorithms and knowing where to apply each because at the moment I use bubble-sort for everything which I've been told is a terrible way to do things.

What would be the fastest sorting algorithm for this integer sorting?

EDIT: It turns out that because I know the numbers are 1 to 5 then I can use a bucket sort (?) algorithm which if I'm not mistaken - and I definitely could be - means that for each integer of value 1, I put it in the 1 group, value 2 I put it in the 2 group etc, then concatenate the groups at the end. This seems like a simple and efficient way to do it.

However since this is (currently) a learning excercise for me I am going to remove the 1 - 5 limitation and try to implement bubble-sort and merge-sort then compare the two to see which is faster.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's your language programming?

Comment: C# or javascript. I'm not particularly worried about the implementation in code at this point though. I want to learn about the algorithm first.

Comment: Did you try to see on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm webpage which sorting algo is more suitable for you ?

Comment: Yes I have been looking at algorithms, but since they're quite complicated I'd like to know which one to start with so I can thoroughly make sense of it. I'm currently looking and quicksort and mergesort

Comment: Integers 1 to 5, people. Forget about *general purpose* sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... which I've been told is a terrible way to do things.

First off, don't accept as gospel anything you hear from random bods on the internet (even me).

Bubble sort is *fine* under certain conditions, such as when the data is already mostly sorted, or the item count is relatively small (such as 200) <sup>(a)</sup>, or you have no sort functionality built into the language and you're on a tight deadline where lack of performance will annoy the customer but lack of functionality will get you fired :-)

This bias against bubble sort is similar to the "only one exit point from a function" and "no goto" rules. You should *understand* the reasoning behind them so that you know when the rules can be ignored safely.

Anyway, on to the question proper. An efficient way for your specific case is to just count the items then output them, something like:

```
dim count[1..5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
for each item in list:
    count[item] = count[item] + 1
for val in 1..5:
    for quant in 1..count[val]:
        output val
```

That's an O(n) time and O(1) space solution and you won't find a more efficient big-O for a generalised sort routine - it's only possible in this case because of the extra information you have about the data (limited to the values 1 through 5).

If you wanted to examine all the different sort algorithms, the [Wikipedia Sorting Algorithm page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) is a useful starting point, including the major algorithms and their properties.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As an aside, the following code (using worst case data for bubble sort), when run under CygWin on a not-very-powerful IBM T60 (2GHz dual core) laptop, completes in, on average, 0.157 seconds (5 samples: 0.150, 0.125, 0.192, 0.199, 0.115).

I wouldn't use it for sorting a million items (everyone knows bubble sort scales poorly) but 200 should be fine in most cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNT 200
int main (void) {
    int i, swapped, tmp, item[COUNT];

    // Set up worst case (reverse order) data.

    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        item[i] = 200 - i;

    // Slightly optimised bubble sort.

    swapped = 1;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < COUNT; i++) {
            if (item[i-1] > item[i]) {
                tmp = item[i-1];
                item[i-1] = item[i];
                item[i] = tmp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    //     printf ("%d ", item[i]);
    // putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will be able to work. Does that algorithm have a specific name so I can look more into it? Just to clarify, in O(n) n is the number of elements to sort, so in this case means the amount of steps required is parallel with the amount of elements to sort?

Comment: @James, I call it PaxSort :-) Everyone else on the planet would probably call it bucket sort (with a bucket size of 1) or counting sort. You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort.

Comment: Oh well I guess I can just stick with bubble sort then. I've never actually timed it I just heard it has poor performance, but .157s is going to make zero impact to my current application, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need sorting here, since you only have 5 possible values. 
You could use 5 containers (or buckets) and as you scan your list of integers you place the values in the right bucket.
At the end, join the buckets together, in order.

Comment: That is a good idea but will not work in my implementation. The integers are actually part of a larger data structure which in the future will is sorted by different properties, like alphabetically etc. At the moment I'm just trying to find the best way to sort by this specific property.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) sort is an O(n log n)  I think its way better than QuickSort

You can find some C# code [here](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/MergeSort_Recursive.html).